# Getting Posts Associated With Category in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a Category Table, a Post Table and a Table that shows relationship between Post and Category which is Categories_Posts

```
**Posts**
id | title | text

**Categories_Posts**
category_id | post_id

**Category**
id | name
```

I have categories like Music, News, Videos.

**Models**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'categories_posts');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'categories_posts');
    }
}
```

How can i display posts associated with each category by the sidebar

I did this

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <div> {{ $post->subject }}</div>
    <div> {{ $post->image }}</div>
    @foreach($post->categories as $category)
        <div> {{ $category->name}}</div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

It is displaying all the posts from each category all at the sidebar but i have a place in my sidebar that i want to display just posts for videos alone, a place in my sidebar i want to display posts for music alone etc.

How can i do this?

I hope you understand me

Answer (score 0):

You can do using `with()` method.

```
$data = Post::with('categories')->get();
```

in your view:

```
@foreach($data as $post) // will loop over posts and show title
    <div>{{$post->title }} </div>
    @foreach($post->categories as $category)
         <div> {{ $category->name}} </div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```